# Add RTL support for a LESS based React library

Tags: reactjs, less, right-to-left, antd

I would like to use [ant-design](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design) to build my webapp in React, but RTL support is a must for me. Since the library doesn't support RTL I was considering to maybe add the support myself, but my knowledge is very basic.

I know they use LESS there to generate the CSS files. Is there a plugin to make LESS output a CSS that supports both LRT and RTL? Or any other method to go about adding RTL support? I don't mind doing it myself and creating a pull request, I just want to know how to go about achieving it.

Comment: you can start with `dir="rtl"` attribute, and browser should handle some for you. for more advance styling you may want to read `http://blog.scottlogic.com/2015/02/13/rtl.html`.

Comment: Thanks @Kossel that's exactly what I wanted

Comment: Hey @Tsury, I'm interested in that as well!
Id you end up working on it? Any progress?

Comment: @yohairosen, we ended up using PostCSS RTL along with some other small hacks/fixes to make everything work... Not something I can actually share, it's very specific. But I'd suggest you start with PostCSS.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if you can create a PR for this feature, for antd team are not familiar with RTL language.

Comment: Already started working on it, I will create PR once I am ready.

Answer (score 0):

RTL support for Ant Design is ready  and it will be shipping out with v4 release.